# How can I insert string value from .csv to SQLite database? Qt c++

Tags: c++, sqlite, csv, qt

This code can successfully insert an integer value from the .csv file to the SQLite database. However, when the value is a string. It does not insert the string value. Please help.

```
   QFile f(csvFile);
    if(f.open (QIODevice::ReadOnly)){
        QSqlQuery que;
        QTextStream ts (&f);

        //Travel through the csv file "excel.csv"
        while(!ts.atEnd()){
            QString req = "INSERT INTO main VALUES(";
            QStringList line = ts.readLine().split(',');
            for(int i=0; i<line .length ();++i){
                req.append(line.at(i));
                req.append(",");

            }
            req.chop(1); // remove the trailing comma
            req.append(");"); // close the "VALUES([...]" with a ");"
            que.exec(req);
            qDebug()<<req;

            que.lastError();
        }
```

qDebug()<< req ouput:

> "INSERT INTO main VALUES(1,2,3);" "INSERT INTO main VALUES(a,b,c);"

Comment: `"INSERT INTO main VALUES(a,b,c);"` text will need to be quoted.

Comment: To avoid that kind of bugs, and most importantly any risk of SQL injection, never build a SQL statement with variable values, but use prepared statements. I don't know how Qt handles SQLite prepared statements, but for sure there is a way, possibly even simpler than your code.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Prapin's answer I've decided to write up a quick how to.

Here is the link to QTs [SQL statement documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.15/sql-sqlstatements.html). There are multiple ways in which to query the database. I personally am a fan of #2 'named binding' over #3 'positional binding'. This is because it is very clear to the programmer what values are being accessed.

[image: How to build QUERY statements in QT]